# How to find the last vowel in a JavaScript string

Tags: javascript, string

I am having trouble with trying to find the last vowel in a string in JavaScript. I found out how to find the first vowel of a string and tried to modify that code but I'm stuck. I tried to edit the `var vowels` and I changed the 0 to -1 and vice versa but nothing worked.

Here's my code:

```
function endVowel(x){
   var vowels = ("aeiouAEIOU");
   return vowels.indexOf(x[-1]) !== 0;
}
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want the character of the last vowel or the index that it is located at?

Comment: "I found out how to find the first vowel of a string" - then just reverse the string before applying this.

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression to match a vowel, while using negative lookahead for other vowels:

```js
function endVowel(x){
   const match = x.match(/[aeiou](?!.*[aeiou])/i);
   return match ? match[0] : 'No match';
}

console.log(endVowel('foobar'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function findLastVowel(string) {
 let pattern = /[aeiouAEIOU]/gim;
 let result = [...string.match(pattern)]
 return result[result.length - 1]
}

console.log(findLastVowel("your string here"))
```

Answer (score 0):

`vowels.indexOf(x[-1])` attempts to look for the last character in `x` (in fact, `x[x.length-1]` or `x.slice(-1)` is the correct syntax), but if this doesn't happen to be a vowel, it won't work. You'd need to iterate backwards from the end to test other characters in such a scenario.

To get the last vowel's index, you can strip non-vowels from the right using a regex and return the length - 1:

```js
const lastVowel = s => s.replace(/[^aeiou]*$/i, "").length - 1;

[
  "foobar",
  "cdgh",
  "abb",
  "baabbba"
].forEach(e => console.log(`"${e}" => ${lastVowel(e)}`));
```

If you only want the last vowel (this is less useful than having the index, which essentially gives you both), pattern match on vowels and return the last element:

```js
const lastVowel = s => (s.match(/[aeiou]/ig) || "").slice(-1);

[
  "foobar",
  "cdgh",
  "abb",
  "beobbba"
].forEach(e => console.log(`"${e}" => "${lastVowel(e)}"`));
```

Answer (score 0):

One technique would be to build your `endVowel` atop your `startVowel`, using a string-reversing helper function.  That's often a general principle when working with first and last values on something you can easily reverse.

Here's an example (and note that the `endVowel` does not in any way depend on the implementation of `startVowel`, only on its behavior):

```js
const startVowel = (str, vowels = "aeiouAEIOU") =>
   str .split('') .find (c => vowels .includes (c))

const reverseString = (str) => str .split('') .reverse () .join('')

const endVowel = (str) => startVowel (reverseString (str))

console .log (
  startVowel ('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'), //=> 'e'
  endVowel   ('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'), //=> 'o'
)
```

---

Obligatory pun for English speakers: Q: What are you when you can't have a vowel movement? A: consonated.

Answer (score -1):

This will give you the last vowel character in the string (keeping the original upper/lower case). If you're just looking for the index of the last vowel, that is `indexOfLastVowel`, of course!

```js
function endVowel(x){
 var y = x.toLowerCase();
 var indexOfLastVowel = Math.max(y.lastIndexOf("a"), y.lastIndexOf("e"), y.lastIndexOf("i"), y.lastIndexOf("o"), y.lastIndexOf("u"));
 return x.charAt(indexOfLastVowel);
}

console.log(endVowel("Find the last vowel in this string..."));
```

If no vowel is in the string, an empty string (`""`) is returned.